# Change value of memory in a debugger?

Tags: assembly, debugging, c++, memory, x86-64

So I got this app loaded in x64, there is a function, let's say
"HeatGainedPerShot", which is basically the value which an object gains everytime it fires,
Such a value would normally exist in the code, but as this is C++, it is simply impossible to revert to source code, thus leading me to a debugger,

So I found it, [well..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXLYU.jpg) the debugger displays many leading to the same adress, but that's for later.

```
0000000140201A9D | 48:8D0D FC7FFF02       | lea rcx,qword ptr ds:[1431F9AA0]      |00000001431F9AA0:"FireMode.HeatPerShot"
```

As you can see
rcx is what contains it,
**Is there a way to do math on it? or change it to a zero,**

- proof of concept:::
- lea **0**,qword ptr ds:[1431F9AA0]
- or
- lea **rcx*0**,qword ptr ds:[1431F9AA0]

**I know it doesn't work, but would it not be possible to do something like that?**

( https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glihs.png )

Comment: Do you want to write the value to that address or just change it before its being used in a calculation? In the latter case you can try patching the instruction with something like `4831c9 xor rcx, rcx` that will zero the value of `rcx` register which will be used later in the code.

Comment: Well, it is the same thing as long as there is 0 "heat" gained whenever you fire, (just the same way you would patch it in the code itself), could you elaborate more on using '4831c9' ? Also, what is with this? https://i.imgur.com/732ygpz.jpg ... ty for your contribution.

Comment: I am afraid your aforementioned technique has not worked as I do not know how to exactly implement it, but here is an image that displays what I am trying to achieve if my post had not gotten to the point: https://i.imgur.com/hHCWS3l.png